# What happens to unsold items on World of Warcraft Auction House? 

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I just went through dungeons to get my level boosted but some of the items I found (Rare items) were being sold on the AH. What I want to know is that what will happen when I put something up for bid and no-one bids on it. Will the item come back to my backpack or will it just disappear?

Overnight I had a bid up but I'm not sure where they went. I checked my 'Auctions' tab and they weren't there and neither were they in my backpack. I also cancelled a bid because I got the prices wrong yet the item didn't return to me.

Answer (score 7):

If you cancel an auction or one of your auctions expires, you will get the item back via in-game mail. There, it will stay for (I think) 30 days, if you do not pick up the item from the mail by then, it will be irreversibly lost.